# Two Divs next to each other with their Items next to each other

Tags: html, css, layout

I am currently writing a page with React Js. As I am pretty new to Webdevlopement especially CSS and only wrote one page before I am stuck. I have created two divs one left and one right and want to place an image in the left one and a paragraph with a link below on the right one. I want the items to be next to each other in the middle of the page. How do I style this in CSS?

[image]

Comment: Hi, perhaps take a look at some of the layout examples https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: image on the left and paragraph on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a custom code solution, without any framework. Easy and quick to customize plus I have included my comments for you to understand each step in the CSS.

```css
.title, .navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.title {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px!important;
}

.navbar a {                                   /* custom styling of navbar items, as they are links we need to remove the default styling of blue and underlined */
  text-decoration: none!important;
  color: #000!important;
  margin: 0 60px;
}

.navbar a:hover {              /* underline each nav item link on hover basic cool effect */
  text-decoration: underline!important;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {           /* give the wrapper a width of 100% and each of the 2 equal-width box 50% */
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex; /* display set to flex to we can automatically align vertically (align-items) and horizontally (justify-content:) */
  align-items: center;
}

.box1 {
  justify-content: flex-end; /* align the content of box one to the END of the flexbox (which is in the middle precisely */
}

.box2 {                          /* same for box2 content but now to the START of the flexbox */
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.box1 img {         /*style the image size the same as the sub-box that contains the paragraph and the link to page in box2 */ /* that's it! */
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
}

.sub-box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">Page Title</div>
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Fun</a>
    <a href="#">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Something</a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- create a main container div for the 2 boxes -->
    <div class="box box1"> <!-- each of the 2 boxes has a common class called "box" that we will style in tyhe CSS code -->
        <img src="http://dev.laurentchevrette.digital/images/oranges.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="box box2">
            <div class="sub-box"> <!-- here we create an extra div/box in which we put the paragraph of text and the link to the page to easily style them later -->
                <span>Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere.</span>
                <a href="#">Link to page</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Also, if you want to play with it to learn, codepen is here https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/vYGdRdm            // If you want to add a border on the whole thing or on specific divs (i.e. the 2 boxes) just use `border:2px solid black` and if you would like just a black line/border between the two boxes, you could add a right border to the left div and a left border to the right div with this : `.box1{border-right:1px solid black} .box2{border-left:1px solid black}` this way your central black line will be exactly in the center. cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really useful :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Feel free to choose an answer as accepted if you are happy with the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Bootstrap Css library, you would get it this way. You can visit [How To Include Bootstrap In HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp)

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6  bg-dark">
      <img src="https://imgur.com/gallery/CSf68dv"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-info">
     <p>
     Paragrapgh
     </p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k23h7d94/)

Comment: Your proposed solution does not look like the drawing provided by the OP and there are multiple missing elements...plus i'm not a fan of using frameworks with beginners as it prevents a good understanding of CSS/HTML, but that's just my opinion of course.

Comment: the approach is not exactly as on the image, but it corresponds the question which was asked. In my opinion CSS library like Bootstrap, makes things simpler than they are. So this is why I think that they are okey for beginners. Using 3 classes and understanding of them, might be more efficient than tons of CSS code.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. It's always good to challenge our opinions with others'. So what I agree on: Bootstrap does simplify things, and possibly, at the OP level, it would be OK to use it to obtain a final result that is acceptable/good. But: Bootstrap also doesn't help to understand CSS, to eventually master it in order to be able to customize, and that's where I have the most problems with these frameworks, it is in the fact that once a beginner/mid-level front-end developer gets used to using Bootstrap and classes like 'sm' or 'xl' or '4st' and so on, how can they integrate into a team?

Comment: Let's say that team or company they want to work within is using another framework or even no framework for a very special and very custom project? That's my main concern. Plus, customizing a Bootstrap-made website is often a nightmare and takes a lot of (wasted) time if one doesn't know bootstrap very well, since you never know what class is modifying this or that element, and you have to constantly override 'default' values or even start playing in the framework code itself.

Comment: So anyways, I think at this level, it is a question of opinion and I 100% respect yours, I just don't share it that's all and I wanted to offer a custom version of the solution to add, along with your Bootstrap-based solution. I think both can coexist :) Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and expressing passion to state your position. There are 2 acceptable ways of doing things. Getting invest time into making or invest the time in learning how to make. It is like trying to catch a fish when you haven't tried it yet. One may say that it is better to make a fishing rod first, to learn all technics and potential of the tool you use. Others, like me would say that you could just buy a fishing rod, try to catch. If you like it, then go on. if not you loose only 20-10 USD not a week in making a tool you wouldn't use again. The last opinion minimizes risks

Comment: I love the the fish catching image! I would probably not even try with a bought fishing rod. That said, I have to give you points for that, because it is true that a lot of us started out playing around with Wordpress and basic frameworks, and then... :)